# Opening a file from Recent Files List

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, rich-text-editor

I have a simple MFC MDI text edtior and I am trying to read metadata from a file upon opening
it....

Now, there are 2 ways of opening a file in my application. One by going File->Open, and the other by clicking directly the filename the recent files list.

So far I have managed to get this working for File->Open by overriding OnFileOpen in the App class, but where in MFC does it have the code for opening a file from recent files list? Much thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For the cases you mention you shouldn't have to override OnFileOpen in the App class. The MFC framework will call the CDocument OnOpenDocument with the filename, whether File->Open is used or the recent file list is used.

Comment: so should i override OnOpenDocument?

Comment: Almost always. Do your file opening there.